# Understanding the role of foreign key constraints. Am I using them properly?

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, constraints, foreign-key-relationship

I need help in understanding the applicability of foreign keys when setting up constraints. I understand that the role of setting up foreign keys is to prevent orphaned data, but I have found a desire to put the foreign key in the child, which seems to break a pattern. Not sure if I am doing this right, and would like some advice if I have my constraints correctly.

Here is the design I have:

[image]

(1) I want all my "product"s to have a type of unit associate with the quantity.  Units being like "Each", "Foot", "Gallon", etc, so between the quantity and the unit, you would have something like:

Quantity     Unit
5            Gallons

I do not want to allow a bunch of crazy units, so I set this constraint up.  This is pretty much by the book.

(2) I also believe that not all products will have an "Image", so I put the foreign key in the "ProductImage" table so I would not have "Product"s with a column with an empty row because I am also trying to "Normalize" the design.

The same issue with "FeeTypes" because not all "Product"s will have fees.

I feel guilt about breaking the pattern of putting the foreign key constraint in the child and not the parent. I just cannot wrap my head around "FeeType" being a parent. This conflict in logic is where I have the question.

Is my design correct, from a design perspective?
Am I still constraining the data properly?
Is there another "role" besides preventing orphaned data?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This may help:  If you delete a record from the FeeType table, and there are existing records in the Product table that use the FeeType, where are the orphans created?  The orphans are in the Product table.  That means the FeeType table is the parent.

Answer (score 0):

There are three cases here (from the `Product` table's point of view):

1. **Many-to-one relationship**, e.g. many products having the same unit type - one unit type per product.
   In this case the foreign key must be in the `Product` table referencing the primary key `UnitType.UnitTypeID`.
2. **One-to-many relationship**, e.g. one product can have multiple images - one image can belong to only one product
   In this case the foreign key must be in the `ProductImages` table, referencing `Product.ProductID`.
3. **Many-to-many relationship**, e.g. any product can have many categories - any category might describe many products
   In this case you will need a connection table that contain `ProductID`/`CategoryID` pairs, with columns being foreign keys referencing `Product.ProductID` and `Category.CategoryID` respectively.

So, the design of `UnitType` (case 1.) and `ProductImage` (case 2.) tables is OK, but `FeeType` should probably be case 1. and `Category` should be case 3.

BTW, it would be perfectly OK to have `NULL` in a foreign key column; it would not break the rules of normalization. So, for example, if some products do not have fees associated, you can have `NULL` in the `Product.FeeTypeID` column. But you will need to use an outer join in your queries to ensure that no products with no fees will not be excluded from the results.

Comment: "it would be perfectly OK to have NULL in a foreign key column; it would not break the rules of normalization" -- arguably, it would violate first normal form.

Comment: "bit columns being foreign key referencing" -- sounds like you have a couple of typos in there.

Comment: NULL in a FK column? I have never seen this in any production environment.

Comment: onedaywhen: Thanks, fixed typos. For NULLs violating 1NF; yes and no. Yes, originally value was expected in every column of every row, but later Codd allowed (actually: required) NULLs. Nonetheless, thanks for your valid comment; I will reread the NF definitions.

Comment: Mike Purcell: Is it not possible that one entity might or might not have an attribute and if it has, then it must be one of the allowed values?

Comment: @SzilardBarany: Not in my experience. When I do FKs, the design is based on the row existing in the table being keyed from.

Comment: @Mike: I was recently working on a DW project and we had a few FK columns in the fact table that were sometimes NULL as no data in the given dimension was applicable. We were thinking about introducing an "N/A" value into the dimension but it did not make sense to add another name to NULL. NULL was meaningful enough.

Comment: @SzilardBarany: Agreed, NULL is better in the situation you described.  Guess it depends upon the design and business requirements.